# How to connect a vpn over a vpn?

Tags: vpn

Is it possible to connect to 2 Vpn ? I mean, I have two Vpn on my pc and a want a first one to exit the LAN and then a second one to precise the exit country (which I cannot do on the first vpn) if it is possible, how can I do it ?

Comment: You have broken English in your question. *"precise the exit country"*  Please provide a more thorough explanation so that we may understand you better.

Comment: A VPN creates a tunnel in which other communications can occur, such as HTTP requests. It is *possible* to have a second VPN tunnel within the first VPN tunnel, but this is highly unusual.

Comment: *"how can I do it"* You have not provided nearly enough details about your equipment and OS for us to answer this. Also I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

In theory all you need to do is to setup a route in your OS's routing table so that the second VPN's server IP will be routed via the first one. You may also have to fix the default route after the second VPN is connected.

In reality, whether you can do this depends on the OS and the VPN client. Android for example only support one VPN natively.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot - or at least should not be able to - run 2 VPNs together as this would create a bridge between them which is unlikely to be a wise thing to do and likely to cause a number of networking issues. Even if your VPN works as a virtual network card which might then be possible to join in a bridge to another network, it is still unwise to do so.

I'm not clear that is what you mean though. I think that what you need is a VPN that allows you to get clear of the LAN. The other end of that would be outside the LAN. It is at that point, outside the LAN, that you would need a machine that not only terminated the first VPN but routed onto the second VPN.

To achieve that, you will need either to find a multi-country VPN supplier that you can reach via your LAN. That's more a case of trial and error.

Alternatively, you will need to run up your own PC or router. Or you might be able to find a suitable VPS supplier that allows you to run VPN's.

Comment: **cannot**? Could you elaborate? I had two VPN clients running on the same machine before, and there are really no issues. You do need to set up routing properly, but that's a given.

Comment: How does the IP stack know which traffic goes where? What happens when traffic goes down the wrong VPN? What happens when traffic from one VPN ends up on the other? What happens when traffic loops? Even bridging 2 normal networks can be fraught, doing it with VPN's is very inadvisable. Setting up routing rules may be possible but hardly a simple or reliable process except in certain limited cases.

Comment: Even having 1 VPN will involve setting up some route. At minimum for "internal" VPN server IP, and possibly also for VPN subnet and replacing the default route (or rather adding 0.0.0.0/1 and 128.0.0.0/1 to be more specific than the default). When you have another VPN, you just need to add the route for traffic you wish to go through that VPN. As for bridging - why is this more of an issue than any other network interface? Configure your firewall and routing tables.  In any case, my beef was with *You cannot - or at least should not be able to*, which is demonstrably false.

Comment: Well this depends on the VPN service. At the network level you can but it is certainly unwise as already stated. If the VPN is a public one, you are probably using a client to do the setup and then you probably can't. Either way, you are assuming a good level of networking skills to do this without making a mess of someone's network. Bridging 2 networks should never be done lightly as already stated, doing so at the workstation level may break all sorts of things and may also break terms of use of the network.